# Gradle error usign fbutton

Tags: android, gradle, configuration

I have problem with my gradle configuration. In my app i use FButton, when I use this I have problem with my version gradle so I change version 3.0.1 to 2.3.3 but now when I rebuild my gradle I have this error : Error:Cause: buildToolsVersion is not specified.

build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dell.eatapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: why do you need fButton ?

Comment: I learn create app and I watch tutorial where is use. This : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ad41Bh704ms Can I replace fbutton ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is rather simple, by downgrading gradle version you changed the needs of your `build.gradle` script.

Just add to your module build.gradle the buildToolsVersion which is required for this version

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"

    //... other android configs
}
```

You can read about the change [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#behavior_changes) that was made targeting 3.X.X versions of the android gradle plugin.

important callout from the article:

> You no longer need to specify a version for the build tools (so, you
>   can now remove the android.buildToolsVersion property). By default,
>   the plugin automatically uses the minimum required build tools version
>   for the version of Android plugin you're using.

So in summary, since you downgraded below 3.0.0 you now need to add back `buildToolsVersion` to the gradle script.

Good Luck and Happy Coding!